# Явное преобразование типов в Firebird

Tags: firebird

Доброго времени суток.
Есть столбец  `А`  (тип данных `varchar(30)`) и столбец `В` (тип данных `double`).
Пишу в вычисляется как столбца `В` эту строчку `cast(А as double)`.
Когда начинаю заносить данные в таблицу, выходит ошибка. Можно ли преобразовать тип данных `varchar` в тип данных `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип должен быть не DOUBLE, а [**DOUBLE PRECISION**](http://www.firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=tipy_dannyx)

```
select cast('0.5' as DOUBLE PRECISION) from RDB$ROLES
```

Comment: хотя это неявное преобразование, но все равно мне помогло мне найти свою ошибку. спасибо за ответ.